# How and where do you define your database structure in Meteor?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am looking at the documentation for Meteor and it gives a few examples. I'm a bit confused about two things: First, where do you build the db (keeping security in mind)? Do I keep it all in the server/private folder to restrict client-side access? And second, how do I define the structure? For example, the code they show:

```
Rooms = new Meteor.Collection("rooms");
Messages = new Meteor.Collection("messages");
Parties = new Meteor.Collection("parties");

Rooms.insert({name: "Conference Room A"});
var myRooms = Rooms.find({}).fetch();
Messages.insert({text: "Hello world", room: myRooms[0]._id});
Parties.insert({name: "Super Bowl Party"});
```

I don't understand how a collection's structure is defined. Are they just able to define a collection and throw arbitrary data into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good practice would probably be defining your collection on both client and server with a single bit of javascript code. In other words, put the following

```
MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection("rooms");
// ...
```

anywhere but neither in the `client` nor in the `server` directory. Note that this directive alone does not expose any sensitive data to nobody.

A brand new meteor project would contain by default the `insecure` and `autopublish` packages. The former will basically allow any client to alter your database in every possible way, i.e. **insert**, **update** and **remove** documents. The latter will make sure that all database content is published to everyone, no matter how ridiculously this may sound. But fear not! Their only goal is to simplify the development process at the very early stage. You should get rid of these to guys from your project as soon as you start considering security issues of any kind.

As soon as the `insecure` package is removed from your project you can control the database privileges by defining `MyCollection.allow` and `MyCollection.deny` rules. Please check the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) for more details. The only thing I would like to mention here is that this code should probably be considered as a sensitive one, so I guess you should put it into your `server` directory.

Removing the `autopublish` package has effect on the set of data that will be sent to your clients. Again you can control it and define privilages of your choice by implementing a custom `Meteor.publish` routine. This is all documented [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish). Here, you have no option. The code can only run in the server environment, so the best choice would be to put it in the `server` directory.

About your second question. The whole buzz about **NoSQL** databases (like *mongodb*) is to put as few restrictions on the structure of your database as possible. In other words, how the collections are structured is only up to you. You don't have to define no models and you can change the structure of your documents (and or remove fields) any time you want. Doesn't it sound great? :)

Comment: Just for confimation, you have to define your own allow/deny rules for every collection you create otherwise all access is granted, only when you're not using the insecure package?

Comment: The `insecure` package is about altering database.
If it is present, the **allow/deny** rules are simply ignored. As soon as you remove it from your project, the clients are **not allowed to do anything**. If you want to grant them some privileges you need to define custom **allow/deny** rules.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question about where to put the `new Meteor.Collection` statements, they should go in a .js file in a folder accessible by both client and server, such as `/collections`. (With some exceptions: any collections that are never synced to the client, like server logs, should be defined inside `/server` somewhere; and any [local collections](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection) should be defined in client code.)

As for your second question about structure: MongoDB is a document database, which by definition has no structure. Per the [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/about/introduction/#mongodb-data-model):

> A database holds a set of collections. A collection holds a set of
>   documents. A document is a set of key-value pairs. Documents have
>   dynamic schema. Dynamic schema means that documents in the same
>   collection do not need to have the same set of fields or structure,
>   and common fields in a collection’s documents may hold different types
>   of data.

You may also have heard this called NoSQL. Each document (record in SQL parlance) can have different fields. Hence, there's no place where you define initial structure for a collection; each document gets its "structure" defined when it's inserted or updated.

In practice, I like to create a block comment above each `new Meteor.Collection` statement explaining what I intend the structure to be for most or all documents in that collection, so I have something to refer to later on when I insert or update the collection's documents. But it's up to me in those insert or update functions to follow whatever structure I define for myself.

Comment: Heh, you were to minutes faster ;)

Comment: :) Yeah but you covered a lot of ground that I didn't.